# Ionic/AngularJS redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have login page . When username and password is correct i want to redirect from login page to HomePage.html page.

**Login.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list list-inset">
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
          </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<label id="test">test</label>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function () {
        LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function (data) {

            $state.go('/HomePage'); // This is not working for me

        }).error(function (data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    }
})
```

**Question:**

When i try below code

```
$state.go('/HomePage');
```

this is not working for me.

I get below exception as below

```
Error: Could not resolve '/HomePage' from state 'login'
```

How can i reach homepage.html page from login page.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Comment: post you app.js here

Comment: i also forgot to add new path to app.js thanks for answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this :

```
$location.path('/HomePage');
```

Full code:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup,$location) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function () {
        LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function (data) {

            $location.path('/HomePage'); // working

        }).error(function (data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: this is using angular's router, now you're handling states two different ways.

Answer (score 5):

use this :

```
$state.go('app.HomePage');    //This is worked for me.
```

My Code:

```
 $scope.Login = function(form){  
   if(form.$valid) {   

          $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : link,
          data    : {username : $scope.data.username, password : $scope.data.password,action: 'login'}, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
          .success(function(data) {                
             $state.go('app.listings');                             
          });           
    }       
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

Use state name instead of a path.  For example:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('auth', { 
        url: '/auth', 
        views: { 
            'nav_view_start': { 
                templateUrl: 'templates/auth/auth.html', 
                controller: 'AuthCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('main', { 
        url: '/main', 
        abstract: true, 
        cache: false, 
        views: { 
            'nav_view_start': { 
                templateUrl: 'templates/main/main.html', 
                controller: 'MainCtrl' 
            }
        } 
    });
```

Use `main` instead of `/main`.

Comment: $stateProvider.state(''auth', {
  url : '/auth',
  views : {
   'nav_view_start' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/auth/auth.html',
    controller : 'AuthCtrl'
   }
  }
 }).state('main', {
  url : '/main',
  abstract : true,
  cache : false,
  views : {
   'nav_view_start' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/main/main.html',
    controller : 'MainCtrl'
   },
  }
 });
<br/><br/>
Use "main" instead of "/main"